# Firebase Auth Registered Email & Password (BusDriver) with Anonymous Log In (Parents)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently develop a prototype android app that do tracking a school bus for my thesis. So the user will be the 'log in' BUS DRIVER (read their geolocation data and send to Firebase sync with their registered id) and Parents (request the selected Bus Driver geolocation data from Firebase and map it on a map in real-time tracking method)

I had done the registered and log in layout for the driver. Should the parents register and log in through the Firebase as a registered ID or just Anonymous Log In / Just a button to go to map layout that receive the selected driver id geolocation data?

Comment: That purely depends on the requirements of your app, something we can't answer for you. But from a technical perspective either can be made to work.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am new to java + Firebase. Do you have a link tutorial on how I can sync between Auth Registered and Realtime Database Data of the same Registered ID (eg: Registered Bus Driver send Geolocation data to Firebase to be retrieve by another user such parents) ?

Comment: There is no single tutorial that tells you how to build your complete app. While convenient in some cases, for most developers that would take the fun out of building something. But the separate pieces have all been covered before. For example: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+android+firebase+store+user+data and https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+android+firebase+store+location+data